# Retorno de Formulário incorrecto

Tags: php, formulário, post

Olá!

A partir de um ficheiro csv, porque após fazer `submit` no formulário não tenho o retorno com os valores correctos?
Se o `$_POST` paises for igual `$registo[1]`, queria que retornasse o **$registo[0]** e `$registo[2]` correspondentes a esse`registo[1]`

```
<?php
$br = "</br>";
$file = fopen("paises.txt", "r");

$codigo = (isset($_POST['codigo']) ? $_POST['codigo'] : null);
$pais = (isset($_POST['pais']) ? $_POST['pais'] : null);
$capital = (isset($_POST['capital']) ? $_POST['capital'] : null);
$cod = "";
$cap = "";

if (array_key_exists("pais", $_POST)) {
    echo "<table border='1'><th>Pais</th>";
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $registo = fgetcsv($file);

        if ($pais = $registo[1]) {

            $cod = $registo[0];
            $cap = $registo[2];
        }

        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>" . $registo[1] . "</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    fclose($file);
}
?>

<?php
$br = "</br>";

if ($_POST) {
    echo "Codigo do pais escolhido: " . $cod . "<br>";
    echo "Capital: " . $cap . " - " . $registo[1] . "-" . $cod . "<br>";
} else {
    ?>

    <form action="eta15_2teste.php" method="post">
        Pais: <input type="text" name="pais"><br>
        <input type="Submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    </form>

    <?php
}
?>
```

Retorna sempre os os valores de `$registo[0]` e `$registo[2]` da ultima linha do ficheiro

Comment: alguem pode tentar dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Não sei se é isso, mas seu if está errado "if( $pais = $registo[1] )". Está atribuindo $registro[1] à $pais

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza eu só queria que quando preenche o pais no form, procurasse no $registo[1] se existia, caso existisse fazer echo do codigo e capital do pais

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no `if` dentro do seu `while`, ele está atribuindo o valor de `$registo[1]` na variável `$pais` toda vez que é lida uma linha no arquivo, por isso ele exibe somente o valor da última linha, troque o sinal de atribuição (`=`) por um de comparação (`==`), dessa forma o valor das variáveis `$cod` e `$cap` só serão definidos quando a condição for satisfeita